# Bouncing back of a ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Physics of simple collisions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6646/physics-of-simple-collisions)

Let the unit vector along the positive x- axis be i and that along  the Y-axis be j. Let us consider a rigid wall with the normal to the wall being along  Y-axis.
Let a ball with velocity V1 i - v2j move towards the wall. After hitting the wall will it bounce back with a velocity v1i +v2j or v2j-v1i?

Comment: $v_1 \hat{i}+v_2 \hat{j}$

Comment: @David Zaslvasky - Why?

Comment: @Primeczar: you're asking about computing the final velocity of an object after a collision, which is exactly what the linked question covers. See the procedure described in Ted's answer there. If you're still confused after reading that other question, you can edit this one to say exactly why that doesn't help you (which probably means showing what you tried and where you got stuck) and perhaps it can be reopened.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky - Where is the link to that question?

Comment: @David Zalvasky - Is the answer unaltered by whether the wall is smooth or rough?

Comment: Look at the top of your question, under the title, just after it says "Possible Duplicate" in bold. Also, the roughness of the wall doesn't matter much as long as it's on a scale much smaller than the radius of the ball.